# how to go to the second fragment when I click the button from some other activity in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have created the TabLayout with ViewPayer like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        layout="@layout/common_act" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I created two Fragment.

to show for the TabLayout
And I have created like below code for my TabLayout activity

```
public class ManageWorkShopActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ManageWorkShopActBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.manage_work_shop_act);


        mBinding.layout.title.setText("Manage Workshop");

        setupViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);
        mBinding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);

        mBinding.layout.nav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBinding.layout.nav.setOnClickListener(view -> onBackPressed());

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ViewProfileFragment(), "Fragment1");
        adapter.addFragment(new ViewPerformanceFragment(), "Fragment2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Then I created the the adapter for like below code.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Then If I run the Application then it will show the Fragment1 as default selected Screen.

In the other way I have one button to navigate this TabLayout activity and also If I click that button then I should be able to go to Fragment2 as selected screen. So anyone please suggest the solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use viewPager.setCurrentItem(item); to change the current tab

Comment: mBinding.tabs.getTabAt(1).select(); This one solved my problem when I click the buttom from the other activity

Comment: you want it for one time or for every time app open ??

Comment: not everytime, When I click on the button then I have to navigate the particular fragment according to the button click.

Comment: Then you need to pass the index of the tab which you want to select through bundle and select the tab accordingly

Comment: Yeah I got that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)`

For Eg you have a `Button btnToNextFragment;`:

```
btnToNextFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(int indexOfYourFragment2)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

just setCurrentItem of pager when click event occur like below

```
 nxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
    });
```